# The User registration form in drupal 7 site

Tags: users

The User registration form in drupal 7 site has only one country under the country dropdown. How to add the entire list from country module?

gbctest.com/drupal7

Answer (score 1):

change the "Country status" of the user's field for country to "both" or enable all country you want